# Having issues with jquery.validator and formhash working together

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to use the [jquery.validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin to validate my form, and then hash the password, but I'm having issues. If i submit the form fully filled in, it works fine, but if i try and submit the form with empty fields, the hash submits whether the form is valid or not. Ive tried all sorts to test if the form is valid before firing the hash function, but I get undefined function errors.

Is there a way I can get these to work together?

The form:

```
<form action="process_register.php" method="post" id="user_register_form" name="user_register_form" class="login_form_box">
<table id="home_register_box">
<?php if(isset($reg_error)){echo "<h3 class='red'>$reg_error</h3>";}?>
    <tr>    
        <td><label for="username">Username</label></td><td><input type="text" id="reg_user" name="username" required=""/></td><td><div id="user_ok"><img alt="correct tick for user" src="images/tick.png"></div><div id="user_error"><img alt="incorrect cross user" src="images/cross.png"></div></td><td id="user_taken_error" style="display:none;"><span class='red error_margin med_text'>Already in use!</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td><label for="name">Name</label></td><td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" required=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td><label for="email">Email</label></td><td><input type="email" id="reg_email" name="email" required=""/></td><td><div id="email_ok"><img alt="correct tick for email" src="images/tick.png"></div><div id="email_error"><img alt="incorrect cross email" src="images/cross.png"></div></td><td id="user_email_error" style="display:none;"><span class='red error_margin med_text'>Already registered!</span></td>
    </tr>                                       
    <tr>
        <td><label for="password">Password</label></td><td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" required=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td><input type="submit" class="submit clickable" value="Register" onclick="formhash_register(this.form, this.form.password);" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

validation

```
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $("#user_register_form").validate({
                rules: {
                    username: "required",
                    name: "required",
                    email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                    }                                                               
                }                   
            });
        });                 
    </script>
```

js links

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

form hash

```
function formhash_register(form, password) {

   // Create a new element input, this will be out hashed password field.
   var p = document.createElement("input");
   // Add the new element to our form.
   form.appendChild(p);
   p.name = "p";
   p.type = "hidden"
   p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);
   // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
   password.value = "";
   // Finally submit the form.
   form.submit();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding what jQuery Validate is doing when you setup your submit button to call your formhash_register function.  Instead, use the [submitHandler](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) option of the Validate library, which is called only when the form is valid:

```
        $("#user_register_form").validate({
            rules: {
                username: "required",
                name: "required",
                email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
                }                                                               
            },
            submitHandler:function(form){
               // Create a new element input, this will be out hashed password field.
               var p = document.createElement("input");
               // Add the new element to our form.
               form.appendChild(p);
               p.name = "p";
               p.type = "hidden"
               p.value = hex_sha512($('#password').val());
               // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent.
               password.value = "";
               return true; //this tells validate to submit the form
            }                
        });
```